# Explanation of performance considerations of read/write on Google Datastore (GAE)?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, bigtable

I'm having a very difficult time understanding the mechanics of the **Google App Engine Datastore**.
I want to understand the mechanics so I can build my database in an optimal way for the database.

Given my example below, can someone help me in:

1. **structure the database optimally**
2. **understand the performance** of both read and write given that structure

**Example:**
Let's say I have N baseball players and each has a unique ID.
I'd like to keep a daily tally of the homeruns hit by each player (storing a "total daily homeruns" property) and basically increment it when a homerun is hit.
So, as time increases, I'd like to show a graph of homeruns each day for each baseball player over X years.

```
Player 1
1/21/2011 - 2 homeruns
1/22/2011 - 0 homeruns
1/23/2011 - 1 homeruns
```

*Read Requirement*:  Read the last 5 years of daily "homerun" data for a certain player?

*Write Requirement*:  Increment a daily homerun count for a certain baseball player.

I would love to understand how to structure the data and also the mechanics of both read and write?  Will this simple storage task scale?  Thanks all.

Comment: Are you going to develop in Python or Java?

Comment: I wonder how the programming language relates to this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would model your requirements with a *one-to-many* relationship like this:

```
class Player(db.Model):
  name = db.StringProperty()

class DailyHomeruns(db.Model):
  date = db.DateProperty()
  counter = db.IntegerProperty()
  player = db.ReferenceProperty(Player)
```

To retrieve all the `DailyHomeruns` of a given `Player` you can do it in this way:

```
daily_homeruns = DailyHomeruns.all().filter('player =', player)
                                    .filter('date >', date_start)
                                    .filter('date <=', date_end)
                                    .order('date')
```

***Read Requirement***:

> Google App Engine performance queries
>   scales with the size of the result set
>   and not with the size of the data set.

This means that if your *last 5 years homeruns query* set contains in average 800 entities <sup>*</sup>, this query performs the same whether it searches over a thousand entities or a million entities.

***Write Requirement***:
Writes are slow in Google App Engine but your scenario seems quite trivial and I don't see any possible contention/timeout problem; 
after all you just need to serially update the `DailyHomeruns` incrementing the counter for a small number of times per day.

***Other thoughts***:
If you need to calculate some stats, for example the total number of Homeruns of a given `Player` ,don't even think to use [GQL](http://code.google.com/intl/it/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlreference.html) for this purpose because it does not provide any aggregate function à la `SQL`.
Instead, you have to design your database upfront, defining a model to store the total count of Homeruns per player.
Using the [transactions](http://code.google.com/intl/it/appengine/docs/python/datastore/transactions.html#Using_Transactions) API, each time you increment the `DailyHomeruns` you will need to increment the TotalHomeruns entity for that Player.

<sup>* I have estimated 3 matches per week for 52 weeks multiplied per 5 years</sup>

Answer (score 2):

There's no single answer to this question. The datastore is really low level and it's up to you to create the right indexes and preprocess data so it can be retrieved faster. Also, depending on concurrent access to the same entity, you'd have to use pretty creative stuff like http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters.html

I can recommend you watching two Google I/O Sessions to get you started
http://sites.google.com/site/io/under-the-covers-of-the-google-app-engine-datastore gives you a low-level overview of how everything works and why they were done this way (down to how the sectors are written to disk)

Then http://sites.google.com/site/io/building-scalable-web-applications-with-google-app-engine will show you how to use that low level stuff in real world applications.

There's another one which presents other solutions to common problems
http://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/BuildingScalableComplexApps.html - nice to open your mind to new kinds of solutions to the datastore's limitations.

Comment: Btw, sharding counters are used for properties that change several times a second. Using simple write for every change would hit a write limit on a single entity.

Comment: @Peter Sharded counters are unnecessary for counting homeruns unless you have a baseball player who can hit more than one a second for an extended period.

Comment: Just to clarify, I added the sharded counters as an example of a limitation (concurrent transactions on the same entity) and solution to that. No direct relation to the homerun counting use-case.